# Ways to ship a package worldwide and get paid by the receiver on delivery?

Tags: international, selling, payment, shipping

I want to sell and ship some products that are expensive.

Is there any way to post a product and get the money from the receiver at delivery? My service needs to be available in Georgia, Armenia, Tajikistan or Azerbaijan.

My customers might have trust issues with such a service.

Comment: I think this is a great opportunity to discuss escrow services.  I'll leave that to someone with more experience using them.

Comment: Welcome Werewolf.  Could you add your country as a tag?  I think that will influence the answer a great deal.

Comment: I can work in Georgia,Armenia or Azerbaijan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fedex](http://www.fedex.com/us/freight/rulestariff/CODshipments.html) and [UPS](http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/shipping/time/service/value_added/cod.html) allow shipping packages with COD (Collect on Delivery) option. You tell them how much to collect, and they will hold the package and attempt to collect it from the receiver and then remit to you. If they cannot collect - they'll return the package to you.

In the (post-) Soviet Union republics, the local post offices provide(d) similar services. If you're shipping from/to these areas - check with the postal service if they have it. However, that may be only limited to the postage costs (I believe that's the case with the USPS).

Comment: Thanks.Can I post package from another country and they send it for me? another question: Should I contract as a Company? Can I contract as a real person?

Comment: I believe you should call them and ask, it depends on where you're shipping *from* **and** where you're shipping *to*. As to whether you need a company or not - I don't think so, but again - you'll have to call your local Fedex/UPS/Post and ask.